# Is the converse of Lagrange's Theorem true for the permutation group $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Is the converse of Lagrange's Theorem true for the permutation group $S_5$?

That is, if $n\mid |S_5|$, then is there a subgroup of $S_5$ with order $n$.

Since $|S_5|$ = 5! = 120, then any subgroup must have length of some divisor of 120.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Do you know the group $\;S_5\;$ only has one non-trivial normal subgroup and that this subgroup has index two? Even better: do you know $\;A_5\;$ is a simple group?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a normal subgroup.  And by non-trivial, do you mean a subgroup that is not simply the identity element?  Also, what is an index?   some classmates were discussing this problem and there were referring to the subgroup of $A_5$, which is the subgroup of all the even permutations.   We know that $|A_5| = 60$ but I'm unsure how this is relevant.   I'm very lost here.

Comment: If you search this site you will learn that all groups of order fifteen are cyclic. Can you find an element of order fifteen in $S_5$? I guess DonAntonio is hinting that you should try and prove that there are no subgroups of order 30. That will work, too.

Comment: In fact I think @Jyrki hint is way more elementary than what I had in mind, which is what Jyrki mentions ( with $\;20\,,\,15\,,\,30\,$ . All three work)

Comment: after some research, I've figured out a lot of the terminology.  My instructor has always used "order" or "cardinality" instead of "index."  By normal subgroups, you mean proper subgroups, right?  I see how to proceed now.  Thank you all for your input.  It really helped me piece it together.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that 'order' and 'index' aren't the same thing. If a group G has order 30 and a subgroup H of G has order 15, then the index of H in G is 2; ie, the index of a subgroup is the ratio of the orders of the group and the subgroup. Also, a 'normal' subgroup is not the same thing as a proper subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ans is no. For example there does not exist a subgroup of index $3$.

Assume that there exists a subgroup $H$ of index $3$. Now $G=Sym(5)$ acts on the set $G/^rH$ of all right cosets of $H$ in $G$. Let $\rho: G \rightarrow Sym(G/^rH)$ be the action. Note that the kernel of this action is trivial. This means that $G=Sym(5)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Sym(G/^rH) \cong Sym(3)$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: The OP says he's not sure about normal subgroups. This answer is going to sound martian to him, I'm afraid.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was just a difference in terminology.

Comment: Why does the action have a trivial kernel?

Comment: @DonAntonio Why does the action have a trivial kernel?

Comment: There are only $3$ choices $1$, $Sym(5)$ and $Alt(5)$ of kernel as kernel is normal in $Sym(5)$. One can easily see that only possible choice is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can see [this paper](http://msp.org/pjm/1968/27-2/pjm-v27-n2-p02-p.pdf) and [this note](http://www.academia.edu/2605307/On_CLT_Groups) to know more about CLT Groups or Lagrangian groups and something more related to your question.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  Thanks for editing the answer...